# Error al acceder a página Blog

Tags: php, wordpress, enlace

tenia una web subida en un servidor windows e hice una migracion a uno linux, ahora que la tengo subida a un servidor linux y entro en una entrada del blog me sale el siguiente error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saben a que se puede deber este error? he probado a cambiar los permalinks y nada, he pensado que podría ser un error del htaccess pero he introducido uno nuevo de una web de wordpress y tampoco ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: ¿Quizás no haz activado el ModRewite en apache?

Answer (score 0):

El error este se debia a que no existía una página de htaccess donde tenía subida la web. Lo he solucionado subiendo un nuevo htaccess , y volviendo a sincronizarlo desde el panel de control del hosting. Lo mejor si os sucede es que os pongáis en contacto con vuestro administrador de hosting.

Espero que os sirva en un futuro.